# Can I pass an RJ45 WAN router port through the RG11 telephone port

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, rj-45, rj-11

a friend of mine just moved into a new 2 story house.
She used to use PLC for her internet connection in her old one story house.
Now, she obviously gets a lot lower speeds, not only over ethernet but over wifi as well, as her router is in a different floor and a different electic board.

It is a little bit crazy but I was thinking, what if i could use the existing RJ11 telephone ports to get an ethernet cable from router the router on the first floor to another routers WAN port on the second floor to "extend the network".

The speed of the connection is 100Mbps, I know that 100 may not by possible but 50 (in the second story router) is good as well.
Just to clarify, there is only ONE telephone line in the house from which the input telephone line comes to the router, if that can interfere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the (aproximate) length of the RJ11 cable within the walls?

Comment: @jvda I really haven't seen the house from up front but I assume around 10 - 12 meters

Comment: RJ11 would not be recommended, with the recommended way to do so being: add a 2nd router or WiFi Access Point to extend the WiFi _(router should be in the center of the house for best coverage and if it has external antennas, the way the antennas are pointing matters)_, run CAT6 through the walls _(it's about the same price as CAT5e)_, or add a PowerLine adapter _(comes in a pair and routes ethernet via the AC outlet)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most RJ-11 ports, especially if they are intended to transmit only telephone signals, will only have 2 wires connected.

Ethernet requires a minimum of 4 wires for a 100Mbps connection. 2 wires for transmit and 2 for receive. Only 2 wires is not enough, it needs to be 2 pairs, as in 4 wires.

Gigabit ethernet requires 8 wires.

If all four wires are indeed connected you may still have issues if the wire in the walls is not twisted correctly, as a result the signal may suffer and you get frequent drops or low speed. Some installations may use ethernet grade cable with RJ-11 sockets, in which case it may be fine.

Ethernet also will not work well with multiple end points as is common with telephone connections. You need one device on either side of a cable, not multiple devices.

As mentioned in the other answer if that line already has a telephone signal on it then you cannot use it for ethernet at the same time. You would have to isolate whatever segment you are looking to use from all other wiring.

Only you can find out if you have enough wires connected or what cable is fitted. It is probably just easier to run a new length of proper cable with the proper sockets at the wall.

Answer (score 0):

If the telephone line is already used to bring broadband to house, the same wires cannot be used to simultaneously transmit anything else.